# How can you write a Lua script that finds a specific line in a text file?

Tags: lua

I need help in making a Lua script that finds a line in the text file `ID_STATUS.txt`; the line is:

```
[+] EM 410x ID XXXXXXXXXX
```

`XXXXXXXXXX` is a HEX (containing only the following characters: `0123456789ABCDEF`).

Then it will cut out `XXXXXXXXXXX` from it and write that new line to the same file (`ID_STATUS.txt`)

```
local f = io.open("ID_STATUS.txt", "r")
if f == nil then
    return nil, print("   Could not read file ")
-----find line 
f:close() 
local f = io.open("ID_STATUS.txt", "w+")
-----write line to file
f:close()
```

I already have a script that can input the ID (e.g. `AD23BC7860`) into the `ID_STATUS.txt` file.
or....finding a line, inserts a line into the  TXT file. The rest should do:`ID  = tonumber(startid:sub(16, 25 ), 16)`

Comment: Do you want to replace only the line?

Comment: The script should find the line.....[+] EM 410x ID... and write the HEX number to the same file. But only HEX number. The problem is that the length of the file varies and the line is in a different position.

Comment: Just found the HEX number save to the TXT file.

Comment: The read ID is saved to the file in the form:  [+] EM 410x ID XXXXXXXXXX. I only need XXXXXXXXXX

Comment: So you want the file to be replaced entirely?

Comment: Yes. I want the file to be replaced entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to *replace* `ID_STATUS.txt` with the matched ID.

Let's fill in the first blank: Iterating over the file's lines. You can use `f:lines()` for that. You'll then have to use `string.match` to extract the ID. We'll use `(%x+)` to match and capture a hex ID; this is overly permissive in that it doesn't check for the length of the ID, but that is probably desirable here. It also yields a simpler pattern than `%x` repeated ten times (10 nibbles = 5 bytes also seems like an odd length for an ID). `[`, `+` and `]` all need to be escaped using `%`. We use the `^` and `$` anchors to match the entire line.

```lua
local id
for line in f:lines() do
    id = line:match"^%[%+%] EM 410x ID (%x+)$"
    if id then break end
end
if not id then return nil, "No ID found in file" end
```

Now for the writing. Don't open the file in update mode (`w+`) if you only want to write; use write mode (`w`) instead. Writing is then simply `f:write(id)`:

```lua
local f = io.open("ID_STATUS.txt", "w")
f:write(id)
f:close()
```

You haven't told us your Lua version; in 5.4 and newer it would be best practice to use the `<close>` attribute on `f` rather than calling `f:close()`. Not only is this less error prone (you won't forget to close the handle, the local variable will ultimately go out of scope), it is also more reliable since it ensures that the handle is closed even if your code crashes.